# How can I show popup form when the checkbox is checked in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem for showing popup form when the checkbox is already checked. I think I might need a script for this case. Please help me to solve this.

```
<asp:checkbox id="additem" class="additem" runat="server"/>
                                           
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="chpPopUp" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none;Width:80%;max-width:100%; ">
        <asp:Button Style="display: none" ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server"></asp:Button>
        <cc2:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" BehaviorID="mdlPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
            TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </cc2:ModalPopupExtender>
        <cc2:DragPanelExtender ID="dpePopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlPopup" DragHandleID="pnlPopupHeader" />
        <div class="modal-content" style="Width:80%;max-width:100%;">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupHeader" runat="server" BorderColor="Black">
                <div>
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                       ........
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <!-- class="modal-dialog"-->
                    <div>
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-body">

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

I tried using the following script but it didn't work.

```
$('.additem').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
     if (checked) {
        document.getElementById("additem").value = "Yes";
       if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as received?')) {
         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
         }
     }
     else {
     document.getElementById("additem").value = "No";
      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as  not received?')) {
         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      }
     }
   });
```

Comment: What didn't work? Did it not show? Did the click handler not get called? Is your console full of error messages?

Comment: The case is relted with WebForm and has no relationship with asp.net core ,it may help to get more help if you could modify the tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:checkbox id="additem" class="additem" runat="server"/>
```

should be put inside

```
<asp:Content ....></asp:Content>
```

and you could Press F12 to check how it was rendered when you debug, and you could try with `return false` to keep the statue of the checkbox, in my case, I tried as below:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:checkbox ID="additem" class="additem" runat="server"/>

<script>
$('.additem').children("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
      
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as received?')) {
            return false
        }
    }
    else {
       
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as  not received?')) {
            return false
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The result:

[image]

The id/class attribute of the checkbox was not the same with what you set in the `<asp:checkbox>` tag.

After I modified the jQuery code, it works well:

[image]